# MySQL very slow with 20 Million Records

Tags: mysql

Doing a simple query like

```
    select state, count(state) as cnt from big_data where status=0 group by state
```

takes about 20 seconds. Here is my table def:

```
    CREATE TABLE `NewTable` (`id`  bigint(22) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,
                             `city`  varchar(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL ,
                             `state`  varchar(2) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL ,
                             `miles_away`  int(5) NOT NULL ,
                             `member_id`  int(11) NOT NULL ,
                             `gender`  varchar(17) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL ,
                             `profile`  varchar(128) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL ,
                             `status`  varchar(1) CHARACTER SET latin1                           

    COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci NOT NULL ,
    PRIMARY KEY             ( `id`, 
                              `city`,
                              `state`, 
                              `miles_away`, 
                              `member_id`, 
                              `gender`, 
                              `profile`, 
                              `status`),
    UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`) USING BTREE ,
    UNIQUE INDEX `profile` (`profile`) USING BTREE ,
    INDEX `city` (`city`) USING BTREE ,
    INDEX `state` (`state`) USING BTREE ,
    INDEX `miles_away` (`miles_away`) USING BTREE ,
    INDEX `member_id` (`member_id`) USING BTREE ,
    INDEX `gender` (`gender`) USING BTREE ,
    INDEX `status` (`status`) USING BTREE)
    ENGINE=InnoDB
    DEFAULT CHARACTER SET=latin1 COLLATE=latin1_swedish_ci
    AUTO_INCREMENT=12889691
    ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT;
```

Even a simple id lookup based on primary key takes that long. My server has 72 cores (4th Gen Xeon ES2690 with 64GB RAM)

Here is a screenshot of explain:

[multi threads http://gaysugardaddyfinder.com/shot.PNG](http://gaysugardaddyfinder.com/shot.PNG)

Help!

Comment: That's not the output from EXPLAIN. Run `EXPLAIN select state, count(state)...`. That will show what the optimizer is doing with the statement. Also, it's very odd to have a primary key of the table being all of the columns in the table, especially when you've already got a non-null column that has a unique constraint on it (`id`) that could serve as the primary key.

Answer (score 1):

Use `EXPLAIN` to show the execution plan.

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html

For best performance, provide a suitable index so the optimizer can avoid a "Using file sort" operation to satisfy the `GROUP BY`.

I'd suggest:

```
CREATE INDEX `NewTableIX1` ON `NewTable` (`status`,`state`)
```

(I suggest that because your query includes an equality predicate on the `status` column, and it is performing a group by operation on the `state` column. With this new index, I'd expect the `EXPLAIN` output to show that it's using the new index, and to also show that the query is being satisfied entirely from the index -- "Using index" shown in the Extra column of the EXPLAIN output.)

With this new index defined, the separate index on just the `status` column is redundant, and can be dropped.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

Since `id` is UNIQUE and NOT NULL, it could serve as the PRIMARY KEY for the table. There's no need for the PRIMARY KEY to include every column in the table. (The secondary indexes are going to be as large as the table itself, since the PRIMARY KEY is going to get stored in each index the "pointer" back to the cluster index.)

If this were my table, I'd replace this:

```
PRIMARY KEY             ( `id`, 
                          `city`,
                          `state`, 
                          `miles_away`, 
                          `member_id`, 
                          `gender`, 
                          `profile`, 
                          `status`),
UNIQUE INDEX `id` (`id`) USING BTREE ,
```

With just this:

```
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
```

(I'd create new table, and copy all the data from the old table.)